# How can use something like scrollTo function for swiperjs plugin

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I just want something like the `scrollTo` function to can scroll to any element I want, Like in the above code I have 10 paragraphs let's say I want to scroll to paragraph 7 how can achieve that?

After making some searches I found that the best way is to use the `setTranslate` function but how can get the position of the paragraph to can use this function?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.5.7/swiper-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #fff;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      font-size: 14px;
      height: auto;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <h4>Scroll Container</h4>
        <p id="paragraph1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In luctus, ex eu sagittis faucibus, ligula ipsum
          sagittis magna, et imperdiet dolor lectus eu libero. Vestibulum venenatis eget turpis sed faucibus. Maecenas
          in ullamcorper orci, eu ullamcorper sem. Etiam elit ante, luctus non ante sit amet, sodales vulputate odio.
          Aenean tristique nisl tellus, sit amet fringilla nisl volutpat cursus. Quisque dignissim lectus ac nunc
          consectetur mattis. Proin vel hendrerit ipsum, et lobortis dolor. Vestibulum convallis, nibh et tincidunt
          tristique, nisl risus facilisis lectus, ut interdum orci nisl ac nunc. Cras et aliquam felis. Quisque vel
          ipsum at elit sodales posuere eget non est. Fusce convallis vestibulum dolor non volutpat. Vivamus vestibulum
          quam ut ultricies pretium.</p>
        <p id="paragraph2">Suspendisse rhoncus fringilla nisl. Mauris eget lorem ac urna consectetur convallis non vel mi. Donec libero
          dolor, volutpat ut urna sit amet, aliquet molestie purus. Phasellus faucibus, leo vel scelerisque lobortis,
          ipsum leo sollicitudin metus, eget sagittis ante orci eu ipsum. Nulla ac mauris eu risus sagittis scelerisque
          iaculis bibendum mauris. Cras ut egestas orci. Cras odio risus, sagittis ut nunc vitae, aliquam consectetur
          purus. Vivamus ornare nunc vel tellus facilisis, quis dictum elit tincidunt. Donec accumsan nisi at laoreet
          sodales. Cras at ullamcorper massa. Maecenas at facilisis ex. Nam mollis dignissim purus id efficitur.</p>
        <p id="paragraph3">Curabitur eget aliquam erat. Curabitur a neque vitae purus volutpat elementum. Vivamus quis vestibulum leo,
          efficitur ullamcorper velit. Integer tincidunt finibus metus vel porta. Mauris sed mauris congue, pretium est
          nec, malesuada purus. Nulla hendrerit consectetur arcu et lacinia. Suspendisse augue justo, convallis eget
          arcu in, pretium tempor ligula. Nullam vulputate tincidunt est ut ullamcorper.</p>
        <p id="paragraph4">Curabitur sed sodales leo. Nulla facilisi. Etiam condimentum, nisi id tempor vulputate, nisi justo cursus
          justo, pellentesque condimentum diam arcu sit amet leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
          montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In placerat tellus a posuere vehicula. Donec diam massa, efficitur vitae
          mattis et, pretium in augue. Fusce iaculis mi quis ante venenatis, sit amet pellentesque orci aliquam.
          Vestibulum elementum posuere vehicula.</p>
        <p id="paragraph5">Sed tincidunt diam a massa pharetra faucibus. Praesent condimentum id arcu nec fringilla. Maecenas faucibus,
          ante et venenatis interdum, erat mi eleifend dui, at convallis nisl est nec arcu. Duis vitae arcu rhoncus,
          faucibus magna ut, tempus metus. Cras in nibh sed ipsum consequat rhoncus. Proin fringilla nulla ut augue
          tempor fermentum. Nunc hendrerit non nisi vitae finibus. Donec eget ornare libero. Aliquam auctor erat enim, a
          semper risus semper at. In ut dui in metus tincidunt euismod eget et lacus. Aenean et dictum urna, sed rhoncus
          lorem. Duis pharetra sagittis odio. Etiam a libero ut nisi feugiat tincidunt vel vitae turpis. Maecenas vel
          orci sit amet lorem hendrerit venenatis sollicitudin ut dui. Quisque rhoncus nibh in massa pretium
          scelerisque.</p>
        <p id="paragraph6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In luctus, ex eu sagittis faucibus, ligula ipsum
          sagittis magna, et imperdiet dolor lectus eu libero. Vestibulum venenatis eget turpis sed faucibus. Maecenas
          in ullamcorper orci, eu ullamcorper sem. Etiam elit ante, luctus non ante sit amet, sodales vulputate odio.
          Aenean tristique nisl tellus, sit amet fringilla nisl volutpat cursus. Quisque dignissim lectus ac nunc
          consectetur mattis. Proin vel hendrerit ipsum, et lobortis dolor. Vestibulum convallis, nibh et tincidunt
          tristique, nisl risus facilisis lectus, ut interdum orci nisl ac nunc. Cras et aliquam felis. Quisque vel
          ipsum at elit sodales posuere eget non est. Fusce convallis vestibulum dolor non volutpat. Vivamus vestibulum
          quam ut ultricies pretium.</p>
        <p id="paragraph7">Suspendisse rhoncus fringilla nisl. Mauris eget lorem ac urna consectetur convallis non vel mi. Donec libero
          dolor, volutpat ut urna sit amet, aliquet molestie purus. Phasellus faucibus, leo vel scelerisque lobortis,
          ipsum leo sollicitudin metus, eget sagittis ante orci eu ipsum. Nulla ac mauris eu risus sagittis scelerisque
          iaculis bibendum mauris. Cras ut egestas orci. Cras odio risus, sagittis ut nunc vitae, aliquam consectetur
          purus. Vivamus ornare nunc vel tellus facilisis, quis dictum elit tincidunt. Donec accumsan nisi at laoreet
          sodales. Cras at ullamcorper massa. Maecenas at facilisis ex. Nam mollis dignissim purus id efficitur.</p>
        <p id="paragraph8">Curabitur eget aliquam erat. Curabitur a neque vitae purus volutpat elementum. Vivamus quis vestibulum leo,
          efficitur ullamcorper velit. Integer tincidunt finibus metus vel porta. Mauris sed mauris congue, pretium est
          nec, malesuada purus. Nulla hendrerit consectetur arcu et lacinia. Suspendisse augue justo, convallis eget
          arcu in, pretium tempor ligula. Nullam vulputate tincidunt est ut ullamcorper.</p>
        <p id="paragraph9">Curabitur sed sodales leo. Nulla facilisi. Etiam condimentum, nisi id tempor vulputate, nisi justo cursus
          justo, pellentesque condimentum diam arcu sit amet leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
          montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In placerat tellus a posuere vehicula. Donec diam massa, efficitur vitae
          mattis et, pretium in augue. Fusce iaculis mi quis ante venenatis, sit amet pellentesque orci aliquam.
          Vestibulum elementum posuere vehicula.</p>
        <p id="paragraph10">Sed tincidunt diam a massa pharetra faucibus. Praesent condimentum id arcu nec fringilla. Maecenas faucibus,
          ante et venenatis interdum, erat mi eleifend dui, at convallis nisl est nec arcu. Duis vitae arcu rhoncus,
          faucibus magna ut, tempus metus. Cras in nibh sed ipsum consequat rhoncus. Proin fringilla nulla ut augue
          tempor fermentum. Nunc hendrerit non nisi vitae finibus. Donec eget ornare libero. Aliquam auctor erat enim, a
          semper risus semper at. In ut dui in metus tincidunt euismod eget et lacus. Aenean et dictum urna, sed rhoncus
          lorem. Duis pharetra sagittis odio. Etiam a libero ut nisi feugiat tincidunt vel vitae turpis. Maecenas vel
          orci sit amet lorem hendrerit venenatis sollicitudin ut dui. Quisque rhoncus nibh in massa pretium
          scelerisque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Scroll Bar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="swiper-bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.5.7/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      freeMode: true,
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        draggable: true,
        snapOnRelease: false
      },
      simulateTouch: false,
      mousewheel: true,
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```